# iOS application crashes only on iPad Air

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, crash-reports

I developed an iPad Game Application and uploaded it to the App Store. But they rejected as it crashes only on iPad Air with iOS 7.1.2.

i couldn't replicate the bug/crash in iPad Simulator. As i dont have an Physical Device, is there any alternate way to test the application other than physical device & simulator ?

[image]

**crash Report:**

you can find the crash report in the below link

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/52i59bkony8ke6b/AAD8zZzekK3dY-7EVJnHa6SXa?dl=0

Comment: They included a link to the article that you should read to be able to understand and analyse these reports, what are the results of your research ?

Comment: Is it work correctly on iPad 64-bit simulator?

Comment: there is a small chance that you have to have a physical device to reproduce the crash, because many things work differently on the simulator then on a real device – regarding the basic architectures are quite different from each other.

Comment: Yeah it is working fine on the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Crash may cause from the following reasons in your case -

1. Are you using any web-service or doing any activity which requires internet? If yes, then be sure that there is network available before calling or sending request from or to a server.
2. It may also happens if your iOS deployment target is less than ios7.1. So you need to check your deployment target too Under Build settings Tab, in Deployment section.

thanks,
vatsya

Comment: the 1st reason won't cause crash normally; the Apple explicitly encourages the developers not to check the network connection first and to handle every possible errors after a failure happened.

Comment: @Nitin yes I'm using Flurry for analytics

Comment: @nitin I want my app to run even on the iOS 7.0 devices

Comment: @iCoder as per my knowledge Flurry was not supporting iOS7, but now they released new SDK Flurry’s SDK (version 4.2.3) for iOS7 support. So, please check your SDK version. To avoid crashes you can write your Flurry codes inside a TRY-CATCH block too.